# Is it good practice to hard-code a camera image path on Android?

Tags: android, image, path, camera

According to my understanding,
different Android devices have different Camera image paths.

Nexus-One stores its camera files into a folder named Camera (`/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`).

All HTC devices store their camera files into a folder named 100MEDIA (`/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA`).

Sony Xperia x10 stores its camera files into a folder named 100ANDRO (`/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO`).

Motorola MilesStone stores its camera files into a folder named Camera (`/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`).

Nexus-One stores its camera files into a folder named Camera (`/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`).

Is there a common camera image path that is shared by most devices ?

If not,  is the API below sufficient to get the image path ?

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
```

Comment: Usually, hardcoding *anything* is not a good idea. I'd go by your last line (personally I've seen devices that doesn't even call the external storage directory as */sdcard*).

Comment: The last line is indeed the recommended approach to get the DCIM directory

Answer (score 1):

> According to my understanding,
>   different Android devices have different Camera image paths

The locations where camera apps store images is up to the camera app, in conjunction with the device.

> Is there a common camera image path that is shared by most devices ?

Not by how you are defining "camera image path". There is no requirement for a camera app to store images anywhere where other apps can get to the images, for example.

> If not, is the API below sufficient to get the image path ?

In your examples, that method would return `/sdcard/DCIM/`. In reality, this value too will vary by device, though not by app.

If you are writing your own camera app, and you want to save pictures to external storage, store them in `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);`, in a custom subdirectory off of there, or in `getExternalFilesDir()` somewhere.

If you are trying to read images (e.g., to write a "gallery" app), use the `MediaStore` `ContentProvider`.